# If value is found, take another value from same object

Tags: javascript, json

Can anyone tell me if it is possible ?

Basically, I want to search through an array of json objects, and if I find a specific value in one of them, I want to take other values from the same object.

Thanks

Comment: JSON is a **string**, and never be an object. So, do you have an array of strings or an array of objects?

Comment: Yupp it's damn possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myArrayObject = $.parseJSON(<string>);

for(var i = 0;i <myArrayObject.length; i++){
   if (myArrayObject[i] == "<your specified value>")   {
        // your code here
   }
}
```